# Java. IntelliJ IDEA помечает @Test как устаревший метод

Tags: java, intellij-idea, юнит-тесты, test-driven-development

Объясните пожалуйста это баг или я что-то сломал:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.hamcrest.core.Is.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class TrackerTest {

    @Test// **здесь не отображается но у меня он зачеркнутым шрифтом как будто устарел и опасен.**
    public void whenThen() {
```

Подскажите это я что-то сломал в идее или что это вообще такое??? Сомневаюсь что сан решил объявить его опасным..)

Comment: Версию компилятора проверяли ?

Comment: pavel$ javac -version
javac 1.8.0_101 .  Вот все хорошо.

Comment: у меня было похожее когда maven использовал, у вас maven ?

Comment: Да у меня maven 3.3.9

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit.html посмотрите это, или поишите как настроить JUnit и Maven..